# Rings which contain integers

Tags: abstract-algebra

Is it necessary for a ring ***R*** with a unity  which contains ***Z*** as a subring to have the same unity of ***Z***

Comment: Suppose $e$ is a unity of $R$. What is $1e$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson what is it ? It's not clear for me

Comment: Well, what's the definition of "unity"? If $a$ is a unity, what does $ab$ equal?

Comment: Are you still there?

Answer (score 1):

Some people require that a homomorphism  of rings carry multiplicative identity to  multiplicative identity, others do not. In any event, if $R$ is a ring with 1 and $f:\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow R$ is a ring homomorphism, then $f(1)$ must be a multiplicative identity in the image of $f.$ If $f$ is surjective, then $f(1)$ must be $1_R$ (and $R$ must be commutative). If $f$ is not surjective, then all bets are off, even if $R$ is commutative. For example, you should convince yourself that if $R$ is the ring of $2 \times 2$ matrices with entries in $R$, then the map sending the integer $n$ to the matrix with (1,1) entry $n$ and all other entries 0 is a ring homomorphism that does not send $1$ to the $2 \times 2$ identity matrix. The ring of $2 \times 2$ matrices is not commutative, but you can rectify that by restricting to the set of $2 \times 2$ diagonal matrices, which is a commutative ring. If the ring $R$ is an integral domain, things work out OK. Let $e=f(1)$ be the image of 1 in $R.$ The $ee=1_Re=e,$ so $e(e-1_R)=0.$ Since $R$ is a domain, either $e=0$ (in which case your homomorphism is the zero homomorphism (why?)), or $e=1_R.$ I assume you want $f$ to be a nonzero homomorphism (or there is nothing to discuss).

Answer (score 0):

No, if you don't require the identity of a subring to be the same (if any) of the larger ring.

Example: consider $R=\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ and the injection
$$
\mathbb{Z}\to R,
\qquad
z\mapsto(z,0)
$$

There is no issue in the fact that $R$ doesn't “really” contain $\mathbb{Z}$. Just define, if you prefer
$$
R'=\{(0,y):y\in \mathbb{Z},y\ne0\}
\cup\mathbb{Z}
$$
and define addition and multiplication as if $x\in\mathbb{Z}$ were $(x,0)$. Usually there is no point in doing such tricks and just an injective homomorphism means the codomain “contains” the domain.

---

If you take $R=\mathbb{Z}\times2\mathbb{Z}$, then $R$ has no identity and the same map as before is still an injective ring homomorphism.

Comment: Here R doesn't contain Z , it contains a subring isomorphic to Z

Comment: @user414969 So what? Just rename the elements.

Comment: I've just edited the question

Comment: @user414969 And I added a comment to my answer.